# How can I make one surface follow the form of another?

Tags: modifiers, rigging

I'm trying to make a paceman model based on the one from the Super Smash games. I'm stuck on having his eyes curve on the surface the sphere. For some reason the cure modifier won't let me select anything for the eye to curve to. I'd try using the project knife but it says I've got nothing selected. I do though. I selected the eye then the sphere in object mode then went to edit mode to use the tool but it doesn't work. Can some one help me solve one or both of these problems? Or maybe a different solution to get my end goal. Thank you.[image][image]

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using a UV Texture, there is a tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scPSP_U858k&vl=en) and the blender manual [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/index.html).  If you want to bend an object around another, you will need to use the shrinkwrap modifier, although you will need a good about of vertices.  You can use a subdivision surface modifier set to simple to add more vertexes and then apply the shrinkwrap modifier to the object that you want to bend and set the Target to what you want it to bend around.

[image]

If you want them to only slightly bend and not be directly on the surface, you can use the cast modifier.  The process is the same, just with the other modifier.

[image]